# Java: IMAP with Apache Commons Net - select root folder

Tags: java, gmail, imap, apache-commons-net

I am using Apache Commons Net and my goal is to get the list of existing Gmail folders. I'm trying the following code:

```
IMAPClient imap = new IMAPSClient();
imap.setDefaultPort(port);
imap.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(System.out, true));
imap.connect(server);
imap.login(username, password);
imap.list("", "*")
```

But it gives me:

```
I/System.out: * OK Gimap ready for requests from 5.18.55.93 fi8mb55620436ldc
I/System.out: AAAA LOGIN *******
I/System.out: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- APPENDLIMIT=35651584
I/System.out: AAAA OK rextuz@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
I/System.out: AAAB LIST  *
I/System.out: AAAB BAD Could not parse command
```

I need the server to provide me with a list of folders because custom or localized ones might exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this

```
I/System.out: AAAB LIST  *
```

gave me an idea to replace

```
imap.list("", "*")
```

with

```
imap.list("\"\"", "\"*\"");
```

which worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> list()

method to send list command to the gmail imap server. Add appropriate

> addProtocolCommandListener

to list for the command response. This should list the folders for your logged in account.

IMAP command:

> A11 list "" "*"

Comment: I was trying this already, but I can't understand the syntax or smth. I'm using the following: `imap.connect(server);       imap.login(username, password);             imap.list("","*");` And getting: _I/System.out: AAAB LIST   "" *
I/System.out: AAAB BAD Could not parse command_

Comment: @rextuz `AAAB LIST "" *` is perfectly cromulent.  Is there something else?  Can you update your question with the exact code you tried?

Comment: @Max I've managed to resolve my issue. I wasn't using syntax right, thanks for your help!